# Fullscreen embedded YouTube videos are off centered on Chrome. Possible CSS or JS conflicts?

Tags: javascript, css, video, youtube, fullscreen

I embed a lot of YouTube videos on my blog. When you go fullscreen with a video in Chrome, the video appears off centered (vertically). The black area is fullscreen, but the video itself is off centered and the bottom gets cut off.

I am wondering if I could have a JS or CSS conflict, but I am struggling to figure it out. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Example: http://filmfed.com/blog/2016-moana-trailer

It works fine in other browsers.

If I disable my CSS, it works fine, so I am guessing it is a CSS conflict of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `will-change` property on the `outer-container` div element that seems to be doing that.

Open a page that has a video, but before playing it and setting it to full screen, press F12 to open the Dev Tools on Chrome, go to the console tab, and paste this in:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("outer-container")[0].style.willChange = "inherit";
```

Then try playing the video full screen. So I think you should find a way to remove that `will-change` property, or change it to `inherit`.